# wsimport how generate ImplService class´s

Tags: java, wsimport

Hi I´m trying to use wsimport to generate that class´s for this webservice 
http://blueticketdb.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8001/MessageProcessing.svc?wsdl

but it´s does not generate the implemtation classes need to "interact " with the webservice .

It only generate a ObjectFactory ... but .. can´t find a way to call the methods on with this factory...

Yes ... I´m new to javax.jws.* :( ... sorry ....

I´m using the command  wsimport -keep ...